# Analyzing a given TCP connection

Tags: tcp, network-protocols, wireshark, tcpdump

I would like to analyze a given TCP connection and record the total number of losses, as well as detailed analysis such as how many losses were of type tripple-duplicate ACKs, single-timeouts, double-timeouts, triple timeouts, etc.
Can anybody suggest a good tool for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you use [tcptrace](http://www.tcptrace.org/). It has more detailed TCP statistics than Wireshark, along the lines you are looking for. (use the long output format)